# Duplicated pages using Gatsby {mdx.slug}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I created a set of pages using `{mdx.slug}` under `src\pages\mountains` and they work fine. If I duplicate the same .mdx file in the path `src\pages\cycling` I notice the new pages will be under `mountains` and not under the other (in the browser).
In fact, under `cyclyng` I will the 404 page.
Do you have any idea about the issue?

I think the point is in my graphql query:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query($slug: String) {
    mdx(slug: {eq: $slug}) {
      body
      frontmatter {
        title
        date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
        hero_image_alt
        hero_image_credit_link
        hero_image_credit_text
        hero_image {
          childImageSharp {
            gatsbyImageData
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Using $slug I can read the whole list of pages, not only the ones under a single path (eg. `src\pages\mountains`)

- I just performed a `gatsby clean`
- `Gatsby.js development 404 page`: [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrhLo.jpg)

Comment: Can you share your project structure? This is odd... Have you tried running `gatsby clean`? What pages are listed in the 404?

Comment: In GitHub is https://github.com/gtsolid/la-corse-toujours

Comment: Thanks, can you answer the rest of the questions? Have you run `gatsby clean`? What are the page listed in the 404 page (those are the pages that Gatsby has generated so far so it's a good debug point to see where's the issue)

Comment: `gatsby clean` yes; How can I share the scree for `Gatsby.js development 404 page
`?

Comment: Uploading an image to your edited question

Comment: ok I uploaded. The question is: how to use GraphiQL to query only a set of pages, and not all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to use GraphiQL to query only a set of pages, and not all

You need to add some identifier to the MDX to apply a GraphQL filter. In your case I'd do something like:

```
---
title: "Cap Corse"
date: "2018-08-05"
type: "cycling_ascent"
hero_image: "./golfu-alisu.jpg"
hero_image_alt: "Golfu di Alisu"
hero_image_credit_text: "AV - 2019"
---
Then in your query:

export const query = graphql`
  query($slug: String) {
    mdx(slug: {eq: $slug}, type: {eq: "cycling_ascent" }) {
      body
      frontmatter {
        title
        date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
        hero_image_alt
        hero_image_credit_link
        hero_image_credit_text
        hero_image {
          childImageSharp {
            gatsbyImageData
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

*Check the notation in the GraphiQL playground (`localhost:8000/_graphql`) to check the filters available and the output.*

And the opposite (`type: mountains`) for the mountains page.